# Range.Find fails when searching for a Heading Style next to a Table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a need to execute a Find across a large document to fix the case of "Heading 1" headers from uppercase to title case. I wrote the following code to demonstrate the purpose (includes some ugly steps to help debug):

```
Sub FixHeadings()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.Content
        
    With rng.Find
        .Format = True
        .Style = doc.Styles("Heading 1").NameLocal
        .Forward = True
        
        Do While .Execute
            rng.Case = wdTitleWord
            rng.Style = doc.Styles("Heading 1").NameLocal
            resp = MsgBox(rng.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Text was found, continue?", vbQuestion & vbYesNoCancel)
            If resp = vbNo Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf resp = vbCancel Then
                foo = True
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem I have: If a table immediately follows the heading, the Find gets stuck on the current Heading and cannot proceed forward. Before I added the debug lines, this would hang Word.

[image: Table immediately following Header]

The code works fine on the text where a table does not follow a header. However, I do not control the format of the document and cannot assume a blank paragraph would be included. I did find that DOES help, but again, I can't presuppose that.

I would use Find All and the Replacement property, but it does not support Case. Furthermore, I tried to use Goto to nudge the pointer beyond the Heading to no avail.

What can be done? Is this a bug? Should I detect if a Table is next and somehow take action? If so, what action should that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: collapse the range to its end, as per:

```
Sub FixHeadings()
Dim Resp
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Style = wdStyleHeading1
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
    .Case = wdTitleWord
    Resp = MsgBox(.Text & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Text was found, continue?", vbQuestion & vbYesNoCancel)
    If Resp = vbNo Then
      Exit Do
    ElseIf Resp = vbCancel Then
        'foo = True
    End If
    If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This gets me 99% of the way there. I have an interesting glitch. Even though the document doesn't start that way, and the subdocuments I import don't end with a Heading 1, one seems to appear at the end. I've worked around it, though.

Comment: See code edit (If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do) to take care of the Style ending the document.